# Array.sort for array of Abstract class extenders

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, abstract-class

i Have class Shape that have one private field shapeColor, and classes Triangle , Rectangle and Circle that extends Shape and have own other fields.
I write comparing method for Shape. (i need to sort them by colorName)

```
public int compare (Shape obj) {
        return (this.getShapeColor().compareTo(obj.getShapeColor()));
    }
```

in Main class in psvm i have next code:

```
Shape[] arr3 = new Shape[10];
arr3[6] = new Rectangle("RED", 11, 22);
arr3[1] = new Rectangle("GREEN", 12, 23);
arr3[7] = new Rectangle("BLACK", 13, 24);
arr3[3] = new Rectangle("YELLOW", 14, 25);
arr3[4] = new Rectangle("WHITE", 15, 26);
arr3[5] = new Circle("BLUE", 4);
arr3[0] = new Circle("BROWN", 5);
arr3[2] = new Triangle("BROWN", 5, 3, 4);
arr3[8] = new Triangle("ROYAL BLUE", 5, 7, 8);
arr3[9] = new Triangle("CHILD'S SURPRISE", 6, 4, 6);

        Arrays.sort(arr3, Shape::compare);
```

The problem is that Shape class must be abstract in my task, but then Arrays.sort(arr3, Shape::**compare**); didn't work. How can i fix this?

Comment: Can you explain what "doesn't work" means specifically? Do you get an error message and if yes what is the exact error message? As far as I'm aware the `Array.sort` method expects a  `Comparator` as the second parameter. Have you tried creating a `Comparator<Shape>` and using that?

Comment: Hmm, all works with abstract. i was thincked that if class is abstract, his methods must be abstract to... my falt, thx)

Comment: in my opinion Comparable<> interface should be implemented and some method to compare values, maybe ASCII sum of characters.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest such an abstract base class of shapes:

```
public abstract class Shape implements Comparable<Shape> {
    private String color;

    public Shape(String color) {
        super();
        this.color = color;
    }
    
    // geters & setters
    
    @Override
    public int compareTo(Shape other) {
        if ((getAsciiSum(this.color)).compareTo(getAsciiSum(other.color)) < 0) {
            return -1;
        }
        if ((getAsciiSum(this.color)).compareTo(getAsciiSum(other.color)) == 0) {
            return 0;
        }
        return 1;
    }
    
    // toString
    
    public int getAsciiSum() {
        return getAsciiSum(this.color);
    }

    private Integer getAsciiSum(String str) {
        int sum = 0;
        for (Character ch : str.toCharArray()) {
            int asciiValue = ch;
            sum += asciiValue;
        }
        return sum;
    }
    
    // finish
```

and Shape extenders colud be as follows

Circle:

```
public class Circle extends Shape implements ShapeType {

    private int radius;

    public Circle(String color) {
        super(color);
    }

    public Circle(String color, int radius) {
        this(color);
        this.radius = radius;
    }       
    
    // geters & setters, toString
```

Rectangle:

```
public class Rectangle extends Shape implements ShapeType {

    int width;
    int highth;

    public Rectangle(String color) {
        super(color);
    }

    public Rectangle(String color, int width, int highth) {
        this(color);
        this.width = width;
        this.highth = highth;
    }

    // geters & setters, toString
```

Triangle:

```
public class Triangle extends Shape implements ShapeType {

    private int sideOne;
    private int sideTwo;
    private int sideThree;

    public Triangle(String color) {
        super(color);
    }

    public Triangle(String color, int sideOne, int sideTwo, int sideThree) {
        this(color);
        this.sideOne = sideOne;
        this.sideTwo = sideTwo;
        this.sideThree = sideThree;
    }


    // geters & setters, toString
```

and after following commands:

```
    System.out.println("\nbefore sort:");
    print(arr3);

    Arrays.sort(arr3, Shape::compareTo);

    System.out.println("\nafter sort:");
    print(arr3);
```

we can obtain results -

before sort:

```
Circle [AsciiSum=392, color=BROWN, radius=5]|i=0

Rectangle [AsciiSum=369, color=GREEN, width=12, highth=23]|i=1

Triangle [AsciiSum=392, color=BROWN, sideOne=5, sideTwo=3, sideThree=4]|i=2

Rectangle [AsciiSum=476, color=YELLOW, width=14, highth=25]|i=3

Rectangle [AsciiSum=385, color=WHITE, width=15, highth=26]|i=4

Circle [AsciiSum=296, color=BLUE, radius=4]|i=5

Rectangle [AsciiSum=219, color=RED, width=11, highth=22]|i=6

Rectangle [AsciiSum=349, color=BLACK, width=13, highth=24]|i=7

Triangle [AsciiSum=719, color=ROYAL BLUE, sideOne=5, sideTwo=7, sideThree=8]|i=8

Triangle [AsciiSum=1147, color=CHILD'S SURPRISE, sideOne=6, sideTwo=4, sideThree=6]|i=9
```

after sort:

```
Rectangle [AsciiSum=219, color=RED, width=11, highth=22]|i=0

Circle [AsciiSum=296, color=BLUE, radius=4]|i=1

Rectangle [AsciiSum=349, color=BLACK, width=13, highth=24]|i=2

Rectangle [AsciiSum=369, color=GREEN, width=12, highth=23]|i=3

Rectangle [AsciiSum=385, color=WHITE, width=15, highth=26]|i=4

Circle [AsciiSum=392, color=BROWN, radius=5]|i=5

Triangle [AsciiSum=392, color=BROWN, sideOne=5, sideTwo=3, sideThree=4]|i=6

Rectangle [AsciiSum=476, color=YELLOW, width=14, highth=25]|i=7

Triangle [AsciiSum=719, color=ROYAL BLUE, sideOne=5, sideTwo=7, sideThree=8]|i=8

Triangle [AsciiSum=1147, color=CHILD'S SURPRISE, sideOne=6, sideTwo=4, sideThree=6]|i=9
```

-- edit --

of course strings of characters in color fields could be compared lexicographically, and then compareTo method could be simple, as:

```
@Override
public int compareTo(Shape other) {
    if ((this.color).compareTo(other.color) < 0) {
        return -1;
    }
    if ((this.color).compareTo(other.color) == 0) {
        return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

the order of the array elements after sorting is as follows:

```
Rectangle [AsciiSum=349, color=BLACK, width=13, highth=24]|i=0

Circle [AsciiSum=296, color=BLUE, radius=4]|i=1

Circle [AsciiSum=392, color=BROWN, radius=5]|i=2

Triangle [AsciiSum=392, color=BROWN, sideOne=5, sideTwo=3, sideThree=4]|i=3

Triangle [AsciiSum=1147, color=CHILD'S SURPRISE, sideOne=6, sideTwo=4, sideThree=6]|i=4

Rectangle [AsciiSum=369, color=GREEN, width=12, highth=23]|i=5

Rectangle [AsciiSum=219, color=RED, width=11, highth=22]|i=6

Triangle [AsciiSum=719, color=ROYAL BLUE, sideOne=5, sideTwo=7, sideThree=8]|i=7

Rectangle [AsciiSum=385, color=WHITE, width=15, highth=26]|i=8

Rectangle [AsciiSum=476, color=YELLOW, width=14, highth=25]|i=9
```

Answer (score -1):

```
Class Shape{
protected String color;

@Override
public int hashCode(){
         //give your definition
}

@Override
public int equals(){
  //give your definition
}

}
Class Rectangle extends Shape{
  private int height;
  private int length;
}
Class Circle extends Shape{
  private int redius;
}

Class Triangle extends Shape{
  //declare your member variable 
}
```

Try to write a comparator class and pass the reference of it with in Arrays.sort(arr, shapeComparator).

and automatically sort() method sort the shape class array based out of it.

```
class SortbyColor implements Comparator<Shape> {
    // Used for sorting in ascending order of
    // Color
    public int compare(Shape a, Shape b)
    {
        return a.color.compareTo(b.color);
    }
}
```

OR above comparator code can also be re-written as

```
Comparator shapeComparator = new Comparator<Shape>() {
                                     @Override
                                     public int compare(Shape a, Shape b) {
                                          return a.color.compareTo(b.color);
                                     }
                            };
```

now call the `Arrays.sort(arr, new SortbyColor())` and automatically your array gets short

Comment: How to close topic?

Answer (score -1):

`Arrays.sort()` will expect an array and `Comparator`.
You can define your `Comparator` like this

```
Comparator shapeComparator = new Comparator<Shape>() {
                                     @Override
                                     public int compare(Shape o1, Shape o2) {
                                          return o1.color.compareTo(o2.color);
                                     }
                            };
```

and you can give the defined `shapeComparator` to `Arrays.sort()` like this

```
Arrays.sort(shapes, shapeComparator);
```